# PHP, MySQL: Loading data through 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have these 3 tables:

**fields**

```
- id
- field
```

**students**

```
- id
- name
- birthday
- location
- ...
```

**student_fields**

```
- id
- student_id
- field_id
```

I would like to load from database all students according to a condition with all them **fields** from the table **student_fields**, but how to do that?
Until now, I have a simple loading students:

```
//$s = "SELECT * FROM students JOIN WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'";
//$students = mysql_query($s);
```

**EDIT:** example:
table **fields** contains:

```
id | field
1  | Citizenship
2  | Geography
3  | History
4  | Languages
5  | Literacy
6  | Music
7  | Numeracy
```

table **student_fields** for the respective students contains:

```
id | student_id | field_id
1  | 1          | 6
2  | 1          | 7 
3  | 1          | 3
4  | 2          | 7
```

**The goal:** for the student with ID **1** I wanna print out **his fiels**, in this case **Music**, **Numeracy**, **History**.

Thank you guys

Comment: Invalid query you have provided. Where is your real code? What are you trying to achieve? Need more  clarification.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Comment: This sounds like an interesting query but.. could you be more specific about what you really want to achieve? You can write down desired output. Fore ie, you want location to be part of a query (with name) too or similar?

Comment: I am trying to get all students based on the `LIKE` condition + I want to get skills of each student. Thanks for the note about `mysql_`, didn't know it, didn't work with PHP for a long time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query doesnt meet your question and u didnt provide more information however you can try this query

```
   SELECT * FROM fields f 
   INNER JOIN student_fields sf
   ON sf.field_id = f.id 
   INNER JOIN students s
   ON  s.id = sf.student_id
   WHERE s.name LIKE '%$search%'
```

**EDIT**
or you can use `group_concat`

like that

```
SELECT s.id ,s.name ,s.birthday,s.birthday ,s.location,group_concat(f.field) field 
FROM fields f 
INNER JOIN student_fields sf
ON sf.field_id = f.id 
INNER JOIN students s
ON  s.id = sf.student_id
WHERE s.name LIKE '%$search%'
```

[**DEMO SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cafe3/6)

Comment: Thank you for your response goodmood, but this is not unfortunately the desired output. Please, check out the OP, I tried to clarify the output. Thank you.

Comment: so u dont need `LIKE '%$search%'` ??

Comment: The clausule `LIKE '%$search%'` I need, because I wanna filter for example all users, which have `Music ` in their fields. Then I need print out all these users + all their other fields.

Answer (score 0):

The Query You are Writing is invalid. To select from a Table (using a condition), the SQL should be like:

`SELECT FROM students WHERE id > 10 AND age > 18`

Also, I Would Recommend You To Move to PDO or Mysqli statements, because as of PHP 5.5, PHP is depcrecating the mysql functions.